# How to delete the "event" data with "eventable" polymorphic relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have tables "events", "eventables" and "items".

I created a polymorphic relationship to be able to add events to all of my models. It works properly. But I have a problem with deletion.

When I create an element in "item", I also create an "Event".

```
 $item = new Item();
 $item->name = $request->name();
 $item->save();

 $event = Event::create(['name' => $request->name]);

 $item->attachEvents($event);
```

I wish I could remove this "event" from my destroy method. All I can do is detach the relationship.

```
public function destroy($id) {
  $item = HealthItem::findOrFail($id);
  $item->detachEvents(); // Function from custom trait, simply $this->events()->detach($events)
  $item->delete();
}
```

I would like that to delete the linked "Event". How can I do ?

Comment: there is a design problem here, how can you know which event you have to delete, if you don't have that information in the request?

Comment: With polymorphic relation, I have a table "eventables" with `event_id`, `eventable_type` and `eventable_id`. These are Laravel's polymorphic relationships.

Comment: Yes, i know what is a polymorphic relation, but for what I can see in your question, you want to remove ONE event no?

Comment: Yes, when I delete an item

Comment: How do I do it then? I'm going to see several models that'll be connected to an event

Comment: $item->events()->delete()?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem could be on this line of code

```
$item->detachEvents();
```

would be good to have a look on that part of the code.

anyways:

1. when you are calling detachEvents() you are calling this as a object method, if the model uses that trait thats fine
2. You are calling detachEvents on an object of type Item, hopefully on your trait you are referencing the event that is created from that item e.g instead of

> $this->events()->detach($events)

the variable $events should be of type event and not Item.